# How can I order dynamic site map in three columns by average height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have site map, I want to order items in three columns by avarage height but it must be dynamiclly. If new item added/removed to any menu it will be reorder again. please look images three columns' heights are same. How can I code it in jquery?

**like default menu items:**

[image: you can accept default menu items]

**after adding/removing items in menus then reoerder will be like this:**

[image: after adding/removing items in menus]

**or another example**

[image: or another example]

This code is unordered:

```
<style>
        div { width: 33.333333%; float: left; }
    </style>
<ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Menu 1</h4>
        </li>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Menu 2</h4>
        </li>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
        <li>Child 3</li>
        <li>Child 4</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Menu 3</h4>
        </li>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
        <li>Child 3</li>
        <li>Child 4</li>
        <li>Child 5</li>
    </ul>    
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Menu 4</h4>
        </li>
        <li>Child 1</li>
        <li>Child 2</li>
        <li>Child 3</li>
        <li>Child 4</li>
        <li>Child 5</li>
        <li>Child 6</li>
        <li>Child 7</li>
    </ul>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h4>Menu 5</h4>
        </li>
        <li>Child 1</li>
    </ul>
```

After reorder, items will be inside divs like this:

```
<style>
        div { width: 33.333333%; float: left; }
    </style>
<div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Menu 1</h4>
            </li>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Menu 2</h4>
            </li>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
            <li>Child 4</li>
        </ul>        
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Menu 3</h4>
            </li>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>            
            <li>Child 3</li>
            <li>Child 4</li>
            <li>Child 5</li>
        </ul>        
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Menu 5</h4>
            </li>
            <li>Child 1</li>
        </ul>
    </div>    
    <div>        
        <ul>
            <li>
                <h4>Menu 4</h4>
            </li>
            <li>Child 1</li>
            <li>Child 2</li>
            <li>Child 3</li>
            <li>Child 4</li>
            <li>Child 5</li>
            <li>Child 6</li>
            <li>Child 7</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: It can be done, but you will need to post some code, have you tried anything already?

Comment: I can't imagine how it will be...

Comment: Do single child items have all the same height?

Comment: you can post the html struct ? 'll turn easy to make a solution, you are using JQuery?

Comment: I have added html code structure could you check again? :) @LuanCastro

Comment: @EdgarVillegasAlvarado no, any child can be different height from others.